# Select item in ListView, then display a custom message (for each item) onClick using toast

Tags: java, android, xml

Basically what I am doing is giving a user a list of terms via listview. The terms are defined as strings in strings.xml:

```
<item name="Bahrain testing">Bahrain</item>
<item name="Bangladesh testing">Bangladesh</item>
<item name="Barbados testing">Barbados</item>
<item name="Belarus testing">Belarus</item>
<item name="Belgium testing">Belgium</item>
<item name="Belize testing">Belize</item>
<item name="Benin testing">Benin</item>
```

I deal with the ListView in myActivity.java:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.seoguide);

      String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.seoterm_array);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.seoguide, countries));

      ListView lv = getListView();
      lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
          // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This is where I kind of come to the end of my rope, I've tried defining it via item name by getting attributes, but that doesnt seem to work.

I suspected an issue could come from not having clickable defined in seoguide.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="22sp" >
</TextView>
```

But I have not seen clickable defined in the XML of other tutorials.

What I would like to happen, is when a user selects, say, Bahrain, that Toast would pop up a message saying something like "Baharain is a small island state near the western shores of the Persian Gulf."

Thanks in advance for the help!

**EDIT**
changed myview.xml to seoguide.xml - which reflects the same information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Use this..

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
              // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
String str_item = lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str_item,
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to just put **.toString()**

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Hope this will work